# What is the difference between a 'page' of memory and a 'frame' of memory?

Tags: memory-management

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_frame) has an adequate discussion of *paging*, which I think I understand.. However I am confused by the articles repeated use of the term *Page Frame*.

I thought frames and pages were different things.  Could someone please clarify the difference.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Short version: "page" means "virtual page" (i.e. a chunk of virtual address space) and "page frame" means "physical page" (i.e. a chunk of physical memory).

That's it, pretty much. It's important to keep the two concepts distinct because at any given time, a page may not be backed by a page frame (it could be a zero-fill page which hasn't been accessed, or paged out to secondary memory), and a page frame may back multiple pages (sometimes in different address spaces, e.g. shared memory or memory-mapped files).

Comment: Also multiple virtual address pages may be mapped to the same physical page frame (often with Copy On Write) and in a NUMA system a single virtual address page may map to multiple physical page frames (to exploit locality).

Comment: I think I covered the first point you made, but the second point is also well-made. Distributed-memory architectures complicate things a lot.

Comment: Yes, reading comprehension failure! :-(

Comment: Could you answer the followings? What does "be backed by" mean? What should be understood?

Answer (score 6):

Physical memory is organized into frames and virtual memory into pages. The "page frame" term is a bit confusing and in my opinion wikipedia shouldn't use it. What they really mean by "page frame" is a block/group/segment of physical memory, which is equivalent to a frame. So they should instead use the term "frame", not "page frame".

In short remember:

- page  = block of consecutive virtual memory
- frame = block of consecutive physical memory

That is how i use it.

Answer (score -2):

A *page frame* is a storage unit within the main memory, while a *page* is the contents in the frame.